# slack api invite bot to a channel

Tags: slack-api

I need to call slack api to invite my bot to channel. I can do that in slack app, but when I do that via api, I always get user_not_found.

I call

```
https://slack.com/api/channels.invite?token=<legacy token>&channel=<channel>&user=<bot user name>
```

I use legacy token, not a bot token, valid channel and bot user name that obtained on bots config page.But I always get 'user_not_found'. How to invite bot to a channel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For inviting a user to a channel you need to specify the user ID, not the user name in the API call to [`channels.invite`](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.invite). In your case the user ID of your bot user. You also need to specify the channel ID for the channel.

**Example:**

```
https://slack.com/api/channels.invite?token=TOKEN&channel=C12345678&user=U12345678
```

The bot user ID should be part of the token you received when installing the corresponding Slack app. Or you can call [`users.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) to get it.

Comment: Yeah sorry you're right. I don't remember commenting on this